# Need help in improving my spoken English

Tags: resource-request

English is my second language and I had a weak foundation in my childhood. Now, I am having trouble in building long conversations with people as I have very limited vocabulary. I would like to improve my speaking skills and plan to build a 100 day plan.

Please suggest a few sites, courses and books to me etc. as I am unable to find good resources.

If anyone has followed a dedicated schedule to improve their English skills, please share it. I will modify as per my need.

Proficiency in English:
Listening: Good
Reading: Good
Writing: Average
Speaking: Bad

Thanks in advance.

Comment: 100-day plan? A hundred words a day? Impossible.  Just turn on Closed Captions in good, recorded TV shows. For spoken American English, try The Big Bang Theory. Just repeat what they say. In six months, your English should have improved.   Also, there are a lot of shows on science, etc. on Youtube in good English which you can just google.

Answer (score -1):

One of the best AI based apps I have tried : **Elsa speak**

And also *Doulingo* recently added a section for practicing sounds for English learners.

good luck ;)

Comment: Elsa speak is not even grammatical.